# Android Camera Prepare Fails

Tags: android, video

I'm trying to build a simple video recorder for an Android device and I've had limited success and mixed results.  It worked once, but now, without changing anything, I'm getting a "Camera is not available" error followed by "prepare failed -2147483648" error

The constructor for the previewer looks like

```
   private SurfaceHolder holder_;
   private MediaRecorder r_;
   public CameraPreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
       holder_ = getHolder();
       holder_.addCallback(this);
       holder_.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
       r_ = new MediaRecorder();
       r_.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
       r_.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
       r_.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
       r_.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
       r_.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
    }
```

And my

```
surfaceCreated()
```

method looks like

```
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        r_.setPreviewDisplay(holder_.getSurface());
        r_.setOutputFile("/sdcard/test.mpg");
        if (r_ != null){
            try{
                r_.prepare();
                r_.start();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
     }
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks, Chris

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not used video recording, but with the `Camera` class for still pictures, you have to expressly release the `Camera` object via `release()`. Failing to do that means the camera will be tied up indefinitely (probably until a reboot).

If you have not called `release()` on the `MediaRecorder`, you may be encountering the same problem.

Comment: That was my thinking as well and I made sure to include a r_.release() method in my onPause() method and all I've gotten from it is an InvalidStateException indicating that the camera isn't active.  I'll try rebooting though, it's possible the first time it worked, I never released things and now I can't get a hold of them.  Thanks!

Comment: That was it.  The first time I ran the app, it never released the camera.  Rebooting and altering the code to call r_.release() worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `camera.unlock()`.

You need to call on your `MediaRecorder` object:

```
setCamera(theCameraObject) 
// I have this after 'new MediaRecorder' and before 'setAudioSource()

//everything u wrote goes in here and then:

setVideoSize()
setVideoFrameRate()
```